# using Gps Getting Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, gps

please anyone give me  the code for,
{
getting latitude and longitude using gps for every 5 minutes,
and send that latitude and longitude to Web url using Json Parsing

## if you close that app also we able to get latitude and longitude

}

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions related to programming. You have a specification, which I assume is homework or an assignment. You need to read the spec, do some research and/or learning, and start writing a solution. StackOverflow will not write your code for you. If you encounter problems while coding your solution, post additional questions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Go to this link to get your location

You can implement a loop with postdelay handler to implement 5 minute refresh rate and run the getLocation inside that...

Use SharedPreferenceManager to store the last known lat and long to the sdcard data

https://mongskiewl.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/sending-json-data-from-android-to-a-php-script/

Follow this to send JSON data :)

Comment: The first link to a tutorial is about 3 years old and now, Google recommends using the [Google Play Services Location APIs over the Android location APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). The Play Service Location APIs are _much lighter_ on battery consumption. If an application is going to refresh the location and perform network operations with the resulting updated data, I think the effect on the battery is of paramount importance.

Comment: but many people not using the higher standard phone .. so i use the feature the gps

Comment: True IceMAN, Suresh you might put this to consideration if support is provided through support libraries like appcompat or something else

Comment: @SureshKasturi: High end phones have nothing to do with it. The Play Services Location API supports all Android version over 2.2 which accounts for **99.5%** of the Android user and device base.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code run even if your application is not open, you need [`services`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) for that.

A `service` runs in the background, If you want the latitude and longitude details you will need a [`LocationListener`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) for that.

If you need your application to send details every 3 minutes, you will need to set a `timer` and get the lat and long and then send it using a JSON.

#### How to Create A Service

**The Manifest File**

```
<service
  android:name="MyService"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/service_name"
  >
</service>
```

**The Service java File**

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
      //write your repetition code here.
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Invoke your Service**

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
// potentially add data to the intent
i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
context.startService(i);
```

#### Get Latitude and Longitude

```
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
  }
```

So, what I suggest you is to run a background service which can take the details of the latitude and longitude periodically and then send it using a JSON.